# Pyspark configuration to process multiple gzip files of size more than 10 gb (individual file size ~500 mb)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, gzip, config

I am a newbie to pyspark. I am trying to process 10 GB of gzipped data. The folder has multiple gzip files and each gzip file will be approx 500mb in size. The data is stored in s3 bucket. I want to understand the right configuration setting to process this huge data. I have tried variety of instances in AWS but the problem is the input read becomes very less after few minutes. Initially about 280mb of data was read in 2 minutes but later even after 30 minutes only additional 20 mb of data was processed. I am trying to understand what could be the problem. Any thoughts on this will be really helpful. Thank you!

Tried on 7 node m4xlarge cluster (8 cores, 16 GB memory, EBS Storage:32 GiB) with spark default parallelism and spark shuffle partitions set to 8.

Total Executors used : 4
Total Active Tasks : 16
Maximum input size/records : 16 mb
Minimum input size/records : 168.5 kb

Was expecting to process the whole 10 GB in less than half an hour but only 300 mb of data in 30 minutes. What could have been the problem?

Comment: Can you please show us the code how you read the files? WHy do you set the shuffle.partitions to 8?

Comment: One possible reason could be memory spill. if you increase the partition size then this problem might go.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the partition size, as by default partition size is 200 and if you increase the partition size, then this problem might go. 
below is the code with which you can increase the partition size.

```
sqlContext.setConf("spark.sql.shuffle.partitions", "300")
```

`spark.sql.shuffle.partitions` configures the number of partitions that are used when shuffling data for joins or aggregations.